# A bug about Region plotting?

Tags: regions

I used one of the examples in the documentation, but by trying all three versions, **V12.0, V13.2, V13.3.0**, they all ran as follows:

```
disks = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{6, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 5}, 2]];
RegionDifference[disks, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, 5}}]] // Region
```

[image]

But the ideal effect should be this:

[image]

Comment: `RegionPlot[rd]` where `rd` is the output of `RegionDifference`. This shows that the region has been calculated correctly. In your code change `Region` to `RegionPlot`.

Comment: Well, this site isn't for bug reporting, please report this to WRI: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback It'll definitely be on-topic if you ask for a work-around, though.

Comment: Indeed, I was initially trying to react to a problem that came up in the docs, and really shouldn't have posted the problem on MSE, but now the problem I can't delete......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With simple regions, sometimes CSGRegion is better:

```
CSGRegion[
  "Difference", 
  {CSGRegion["Union", {Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{6, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 5}, 2]}], 
   Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, 5}}]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

disks = RegionUnion[
   Disk[{0, 0}, 2],
   Disk[{6, 0}, 2], Disk[{3, 5}, 2]];

RegionDifference[disks, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, 5}}]] // Region
```

[image]

```
disks = RegionUnion[
   Disk[{0, 0}, 2] // DiscretizeGraphics,
   Disk[{6, 0}, 2] // DiscretizeGraphics, 
   Disk[{3, 5}, 2] // DiscretizeGraphics];

RegionDifference[disks, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {3, 5}}]] // Region
```

[image]